# How to cast date as date string in PRESTO

Tags: sql, presto

I did the following to convert DATE into a DATE STRING

```
SELECT 
cast(date(from_unixtime(time)) as date_string) as dateid
from table A
```

but was returned an error - line 3:1: Unknown type: date_string. Does anyone know what is wrong with my CAST syntax?

Comment: What is a `date_string`?  Why not just use something like `varchar(255)`?

Comment: Meaning to convert it into a string of text instead of being in a date format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like:

```
CAST(your_date_value AS varchar)
```

(replace "date_string" with "varchar")